# Selecting Polygon on Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, maps

My project is to create a zone management module for a online business.

The business owner / admin can create new zones by drawing them as POLYGONS on a google map.

I am able to draw polygons, select between them fetch the coordinates and save them without any problem.

However when i try to fetch the existing coordinates stored in the database and draw them on screen, they get rendered properly, but i am not able to select them.

I have been using google's code samples to test out the functionality.

The Code i am using to draw existing coordinates is

```
var triangleCoords = [
new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
];

// Construct the polygon.
bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
paths: triangleCoords,
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 0.8,
strokeWeight: 2,
fillColor: '#FF0000',
fillOpacity: 0.35
});

bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The Code i am using for Drawing Polygons on the screen using the Drawing Manager is also from a Google sample

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.344, 114.048),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoomControl: true
    });

    var polyOptions = {
      strokeWeight: 0,
      fillOpacity: 0.45,
      editable: true
    };
    // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw
    // markers, lines, and shapes.
    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      markerOptions: {
        draggable: true
      },
      polylineOptions: {
        editable: true
      },
      rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
      circleOptions: polyOptions,
      polygonOptions: polyOptions,
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
        // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

        // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
        // mouses down on it.
        var newShape = e.overlay;
        newShape.type = e.type;
        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
          setSelection(newShape);
        });
        setSelection(newShape);
      }
    });

    // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
    // map is clicked.
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);

    buildColorPalette();
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Since the function i am using to select between the polygons checks for overlay complete using the drawing manager,

```
google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
```

i am not able to select polygons drawn using

```
google.maps.Polygon
```

so tldr

1 ) how do i check if i am selecting a Polygon on google maps ?

OR

2) How do i draw pre defined polygon points using the Drawing Manager?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *selecting a Polygon*? Clicking on it?

Comment: Do you have multiple initialize functions?  Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?  I get a javascript error with the posted code `Uncaught ReferenceError: clearSelection is not defined`

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteSelectedShape is not defined`

Comment: Yes selecting a Polygon by Clicking on It.

Comment: working code : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEvGYE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a click event listener to your polygon and get its paths:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, 'click', function () {
    var polygonPaths = this.getPaths();
});
```

Check the documented [Polygon methods and events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon).

Comment: I have tried in code pen, working code for my issue.        http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEvGYE